# How do I add payload for requestjs REST call

Tags: node.js, rest, express, request

I've the following code:

```
var request = require('request')
...
var options = {
    method: 'post',
    rejectUnauthorized: false, 
    url: '<my rest URI>',
    headers: {
    'content-type':json},
    Authorization:'Basic',
    auth: {
       user: username,
       password: password
    } 
}
```

...

```
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        retmessage= err;
        res.render(err);
          return;
      }
      console.dir('headers', res.headers)
      console.dir('status code', res.statusCode)
      console.dir(body)
    })
```

I'm trying to invoke a REST API which needs json data payload. How do I add the payload to this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a body property in your options object. From https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback:

> body - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a Buffer
>   or String, unless json is true. If json is true, then body must be a
>   JSON-serializable object.